# How to with url parameters from two models?

Tags: python, django

I want to create real time chat with channels, and i should put parameters to my RoomDetail from 2 models to use them in the urls like `path('<str:room_name>/<str:person_name>/',RoomDetail.as_view(),name='showchat')`
how to add additional User model to get username parameter and put it to my url?

```
views.py
class RoomDetail(DetailView):
model = Room
template_name = 'rooms/room_detail.html'
context_object_name = 'room_detail'
slug_field = 'invite_url'
slug_url_kwarg = 'url'

consumers.py 
class Consumer(WebsocketConsumer):
def connect(self):
    self.person_name=self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['person_name']
    self.room_name=self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
    self.room_group_name='chat_%s' % self.room_name

    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
        self.room_group_name,
        self.channel_name
    )

    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
        self.room_group_name,
        {
            "type":"chat_message",
            "message":self.person_name+" Joined Chat"
        }
    )
    self.accept()

def disconnect(self, code):
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
        self.room_group_name,
        {
            "type":"chat_message",
            "message":self.person_name+" Left Chat"
        }
    )
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
        self.room_group_name,
        self.channel_name
    )
def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
    text_data_json=json.loads(text_data)
    message=text_data_json['message']

    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
        self.room_group_name,
        {
            'type':'chat_message',
            'message':self.person_name+" : "+message
        }
    )

def chat_message(self,event):
    message=event['message']

    self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
        'message':message
    }))
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What part of your code do we have to look at that isn't working?

Comment: look i have room detail view from it i am getting room_name parameter for my url, and i should get person_name(username) from User model, but i don't know how to use two models in one view

Comment: Use a function-based view. If the django generic views don't fit the purpose, don't use them. Or override the `get_object()` method of the `DetailView` but it might look a bit complex if you're using the `slug_field` and `slug_url_kwarg` params.